# After Installing the JBoss Server I am not able to access the jmx console

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I am completely new to Jboss. I have seen in some tutorials after unzipping the zip file  to access the JMX-console, I have to hit the url like `http://localhost:8080/jmx-console`. But its giving a "Page not found" exception.

`Jboss - version : jboss-eap-6.3.0.Beta`

`OS : Windows 7 64-bit`

I execute the `standalone.dat` and the server is running fine but not able to access the console.
Please help me ?

Comment: have you tried accessing the console by pointing your browser to this url? http://localhost:8080/admin-console

Comment: @Lucky : the admin console is http://localhost:9990/console. I also tried http://localhost:9990/jmx-console.

Comment: Do you have any ERROR or WARN in your log if you start? check your "<jbosshome>/server/default/deploy" folder for jmx-console war file and hit localhost:8080 or localhost:9990..if u see not found for both of them..you may have configured a different port..check this post https://developer.jboss.org/thread/175801?tstart=0

Comment: There is no server folder. The folders I got after unzipping it is like below.

1).installation
2)appclient
3)bin
4)bundles
5)docs
6)domain
7)modules
8)standalone
9)welcome-content

Answer (score 3):

JMX console was a feature of JBoss AS 6 (and previous versions). From JBoss AS 7, JMX console has been dropped and replaced with a real admin console. And JBoss EAP 6 is based on JBoss AS 7 (I know, those names & version numbers are a bit confusing).

You'll find a complete explanation on how to use it in the [EAP documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-The_Management_Console.html). If you want a shorter version :

- add a management user, with the bin/add-user.sh (or .bat) script
- start JBoss
- access to http://localhost:9990 and log in with the previously created credentials